Starship/Matisse HD Audio Controller not being claimed in ubuntu 24.04
Had this issue in 22.04, upgraded to 24.04 hoping to fix it, but no change. After some searching on here and google I've got the following information, but no solution:

lshw shows:
$ sudo lshw -class multimedia
  *-usb:0                   
       description: Video
       product: Elgato Facecam: Elgato Facecam
       vendor: Elgato
       physical id: 1
       bus info: usb@4:1.1
       logical name: input29
       logical name: /dev/input/event23
       version: 1.00
       serial: FW21K1A19874
       capabilities: usb-3.00 usb
       configuration: driver=usbhid maxpower=696mA speed=5000Mbit/s
  *-usb
       description: Video
       product: HDMI to U3 capture
       vendor: Video Grabber
       physical id: 1
       bus info: usb@4:1.2.1
       logical name: card1
       logical name: /dev/snd/controlC1
       logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC1D0c
       version: 1.05
       serial: 20000130041415
       capabilities: usb-3.00
       configuration: driver=snd-usb-audio maxpower=600mA speed=5000Mbit/s
  *-multimedia UNCLAIMED
       description: Audio device
       product: Starship/Matisse HD Audio Controller
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
       physical id: 0.4
       bus info: pci@0000:2f:00.4
       version: 00
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:c0400000-c0407fff
  *-multimedia
       description: Audio device
       product: AD102 High Definition Audio Controller
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0.1
       bus info: pci@0000:41:00.1
       logical name: card2
       logical name: /dev/snd/controlC2
       logical name: /dev/snd/hwC2D0
       logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC2D3p
       logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC2D7p
       logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC2D8p
       logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC2D9p
       version: a1
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
       resources: irq:470 memory:f3080000-f3083fff
  *-multimedia
       description: Audio device
       product: AD102 High Definition Audio Controller
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0.1
       bus info: pci@0000:61:00.1
       logical name: card0
       logical name: /dev/snd/controlC0
       logical name: /dev/snd/hwC0D0
       logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC0D3p
       logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC0D7p
       logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC0D8p
       logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC0D9p
       version: a1
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
       resources: irq:469 memory:f7080000-f7083fff


I've veried that snd_usb_audio is loaded:
$ cat /proc/modules| grep  snd_usb      
snd_usb_audio 495616 1 - Live 0x0000000000000000
snd_usbmidi_lib 53248 1 snd_usb_audio, Live 0x0000000000000000
snd_ump 45056 1 snd_usb_audio, Live 0x0000000000000000
snd_hwdep 20480 2 snd_usb_audio,snd_hda_codec, Live 0x0000000000000000
snd_rawmidi 57344 3 snd_usbmidi_lib,snd_ump,snd_seq_midi, Live 0x0000000000000000
snd_pcm 192512 5 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_usb_audio,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_core, Live 0x0000000000000000
mc 81920 9 snd_usb_audio,uvcvideo,videobuf2_v4l2,videodev,videobuf2_common, Live 0x0000000000000000
snd 143360 20 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_usb_audio,snd_hda_codec,snd_usbmidi_lib,snd_ump,snd_hwdep,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq,snd_pcm,snd_seq_device,snd_timer, Live 0x0000000000000000


If I check on messages from snd_hda_intel, I can see the audio device is in its denylist (last message):
$ sudo dmesg | grep snd_hda_intel
[   20.121760] snd_hda_intel 0000:61:00.1: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[   20.121860] snd_hda_intel 0000:61:00.1: Disabling MSI
[   20.121868] snd_hda_intel 0000:61:00.1: Handle vga_switcheroo audio client
[   20.122000] snd_hda_intel 0000:41:00.1: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[   20.122058] snd_hda_intel 0000:41:00.1: Disabling MSI
[   20.122067] snd_hda_intel 0000:41:00.1: Handle vga_switcheroo audio client
[   20.122159] snd_hda_intel 0000:2f:00.4: Skipping the device on the denylist



